# App works fine on emulators, but crashes on device with: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__aeabi_memcpy"

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk, libsvm

I'm trying to implement yctung's [AndroidLibSvm](https://github.com/yctung/AndroidLibSVM) into my project with Android Studio 3.2.1. While the app works fine on any emulated device (I tried Android 23 and 28, both worked flawlessly), it crashes on my real device (a lenovo tablet with Android 6.0) with the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__aeabi_memcpy" referenced by "/data/app/com.krautkremer.nils.mymirror-2/lib/arm/libjnilibsvm.so"
```

as soon as the app tries to run the part of the code that uses cytung's lib. 
There are a few similar cases on SO e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39970974/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-dlopen-failed-cannot-locate-symbol-aeabi-mem) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32845956/android-m-crash-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-dlopen-failed) but setting my

```
arguments "-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-23"
```

or any other android-x and my targetSdkVersion to 23 in the build.gradle didn't solve it.

this is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.krautkremer.nils.mymirror"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags ""
            arguments "-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-23"
        }
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    //exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
}

externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "CMakeLists.txt"


    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'
implementation 'androidx.media:media:1.1.0-alpha01'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha2'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha01'
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:18.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common:16.1.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:17.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1-alpha01'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1-alpha01'
implementation project(':androidlibsvm-release')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I even downgraded my NDK version from 18 to 15 with no success.
Any ideas what might be the problem?

> Help me, Obi-Wan Kenobi. You're my only hope.

EDIT:
This is my CMakeLists.txt, if it is of any help. I didn't change anything, should I?

```
# For more information about using CMake with Android Studio, read the
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        native-lib

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp)

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
        log-lib

        # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
        # you want CMake to locate.
        log)

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        native-lib

        # Links the target library to the log library
        # included in the NDK.
        ${log-lib})
```

Comment: If LibSVM crashes, ensure your input options follow the original LibSVM format

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But is it even possible, that there is smth wrong with the input format/optinons even if the app works fine on an emulated device?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your **minSdkVersion** and **targetSdkVersion**, i.e.

```
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 23
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me! 
I tried a bunch of combinations of min- and target Sdkversions but none of them worked.

Comment: That's unnecessary. It's crashing on Android 6.0, which is API level 23. The minSdkVersion shown above should be fine.